# Android Intent Service implementing SensorEventListener

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent

I have a question about IntentService in Android. I define my own service as below:

```
public class ABC extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener {

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { }
}
```

Now if i start the service from other activity, `onHandleIntent()` is invoked. Documentation says it launches a worker thread to process the request. However, when `onSensorChanged()` method is invoked, which thread will be executing the code defined in `onSensorChanged()` method. Will it be the worker thread or the main application thread???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [IntentService source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java), IntentServices stop themselves when they no longer have any messages (the `stopSelf` call). Therefore if you want a long running `Service` (which I assume would be appropriate for your `SensorEventListener`), then you should use a regular `Service`.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. What I'm trying to understand is how IntentService is serving the request in above two cases. onHandleIntent() and onSensorChanged(). onHandleIntent() launches a worker thread and stops by itself on completion. What about onSensorChanged()??? Which thread is actually invoked to handle this request?

Comment: @pree - after the worker thread finishes handling all messages, **it stops the whole IntentService**, meaning there's nothing to receive your sensor changed events. If you were using a regular `Service` (that wouldn't be stopped), then `onSensorChanged()`, like every method in a `Service`, would be called on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, I got it. It will be invoked on main thread. Also, I did a small experiment and invoked onHandleInvoked() method using startService(). It stopped after it finished the request. Then I touched the sensor to invoke onSensorChanged() method and it was invoked on main thread. How? If the whole service stopped after finishing the first request, how come it was able to detect sensor changes???