# Capture Shake Gesture when app is in background or in killed state Android as well iOS

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I am implementing an App in which I want to send notifications to friends when users shake their phone. This should work even if app is running in background. Could anyone please help with idea

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it is simply not possible, as you don't get these kind of events while the app is in the background.

On Android it is possible right now because Titanium has no support for it. However, it is possible natively on Android ([as demonstrated by this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126062/how-can-my-intentservice-in-background-always-listen-to-devices-shake)).

You can wrap this functionality in a module by following the [guides](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Project) at the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Quick_Start).

Good luck.